# How do i return to the beginning of my code/have a nested loop?

Tags: python, string, loops, nested

I want my code to run so that if the condition is not met (in the if loop) it will return to the beginning of the code, asking the user to input another sentence. How do i add this nested loop (if that is what it's called)?

```
sentence = input("Please input a sentence: ")
word = input("Please input a word: ")
sentence = sentence.lower()
word = word.lower()
wordlist = sentence.split(' ')
print ("Your word, {0}, is in positions:".format (word))
for position,w in enumerate(wordlist):
    if w == word:
        print("{0}".format(position+1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put a `while` loop around your code and `break` or `continue` depending on the input:

```
while True:
     sentence = input("Please input a sentence: ")
     if bad(sentence): # replace with actual condition
         continue
     ...
     for position, w in enumerate(wordlist):
         ...
     break
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
while True:
    sentence = input("Please input a sentence: ")
    if sentence.lower() == "quit": break
    word = input("Please input a word: ")
    sentence = sentence.lower()
    word = word.lower()
    wordlist = sentence.split(' ')
    print ("Your word, {0}, is in positions:".format (word))
    for position,w in enumerate(wordlist):
        if w == word:
            print("{0}".format(position+1))
```

Comment: This is definitely an infinite loop

Comment: @cricket_007 regarding your question in the now-deleted Mohammed's answer,  the `break` was inside the nested `for` loop and that breaks out of for loop, not out of the outer while loop

Comment: Yes, of course… Po can easily ask or exit of the loop, no?

Comment: @Aprillion - Yeah, I realized that right before you commented

Comment: I've add a exit for the loop